# Member Count channel showing up as 0 members

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was creating a function that runs every second and updates a channel name to show the number of members in my server but it is just showing up as 0 members. There a no errors for the command. Here is the code:

```js
    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("778322604863258686")
    setInterval(function () {
        var memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
        var memberCountChannel = bot.channels.cache.get("779888675915169802");
        memberCountChannel.setName(`${memberCount}`)
    }, 1000);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the new [intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html) feature that discord implemented, you must go to the developer portal and enable the server members intent:
[image]
And, your client must be instantiated with the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ws: {intents: ["GUILD_MEMBERS"]}});
```